# Regular expressions not working

Tags: php, regex

I am not a coder, but i am trying to make an regex for something like this:

```
http://www.somedomain.com/340999
```

I have made all of this and it dint work, in my xenforo addon

```
http://[\w\.]*?somedomain\.[a-z]+/(\w+)
/http:\/\/(www\.)?somedomain\.com\/[0-9]/
http://[\w\.]*?somedomain\.[a-z]+/(?P<sval1>[\w-]+)
http://[a-z\.]*?somedomain\.[a-z]+/(\d+)
```

the error is

```
Server Error
preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '#' found
```

maybe a problem with the code?

Comment: I would be careful clicking that link folks...

Comment: @codebox the OP is at least honest, the most people would replace it with mydomain.org :D

Comment: So you basically want to detect that links and than? Replace them or what?

Comment: Sorry about that friends.

Comment: replace the links @rekire.

Comment: Would help if i put the code?

Comment: Yes it would help to see the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try [preg-replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instad:

```
$search = '/(http:\/\/)?(www\.)?(somedomain\.com)(|\/[0-9]+)/i';
$replacement = '-consored-';
echo preg_replace($search, $replacement, $input);
```

The regular expression above will catch all links even if there is no *http* prefix or the *www.*.